# Semantics of GNU make's multi-line variable assignment operator

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Adapting an example from the manual:

```
define reverse =
$(2) $(1)
endef

foo = $(call reverse,a,b)

$(info $(foo))
```

Prints nothing.  However, when the `=` operator is removed from the definition of `reverse`, make prints `b a`.

Why do these behave differently, given that the manual states:

> You may omit the variable assignment operator if you prefer. If
>   omitted, make assumes it to be ‘=’

Comment: The assignment operator is permitted in Gnu make 3.82, but not 3.81. What version of make are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.81.  Do you have a link to some info on what has changed?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by _what has changed_, but if you read the `NEWS` file that comes with the GNU make distribution it describes all the user-visible changes in each release.  You can see the latest version here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS

Comment: The NEWS file in http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.82.tar.bz2 says: "The 'define' make directive now allows a variable assignment operator after the variable name, to allow for simple, conditional, or appending multi-line variable assignment."  Also, the manual that you read about the use of the variable assignment operator has a version identifier.  I would expect you're looking at version 3.82 or newer.